# Cross platrform way to identify current opengl rendering context?

Tags: opengl

I have discovered that some OpenGL objects, such as shaders, are not shared between rendering contexts and will raise a `GL_INVALID_VALUE` error if used in the wrong context.

So my library has something like this (assume C++ wrappers around the OpenGL IDs):

```
const char * const VERTEX_SHADER_LIB = "...";
const char * const FRAGMENT_SHADER_LIB = "...";

ShaderProgram shader (FragmentShader plugin)
{
    ShaderProgram p;
    p .attach (VerexShader (VERTEX_SHADER_LIB));
    p .attach (FragmentShader (FRAGMENT_SHADER_LIB));
    p .attach (plugin);
    p .link ();
    return p;
}
```

In the interests of efficiency, I rewrite it along these lines:

```
VertexShader vertex_shader_lib ()
{
    static VertexShader SHADER (VERTEX_SHADER_LIB);
    return SHADER;
}

FragmentShader fragment_shader_lib ()
{
    static FragmentShader SHADER (FRAGMENT_SHADER_LIB);
    return SHADER;
}

ShaderProgram shader (FragmentShader plugin)
{
    ShaderProgram p;
    p .attach (vertex_shader_lib ());
    p .attach (fragment_shader_lib ());
    p .attach (plugin);
    p .link ();
    return p;
}
```

but this more efficient version only works if used for a single rendering context.

I would therefore need to rewrite it like this:

```
VertexShader vertex_shader_lib ()
{
    static Map <RenderContextID, VertexShader> SHADERS;

    SHADERS .insert_if_key_does_not_exist (
        current_render_context (),
        VertexShader (VERTEX_SHADER_LIB));

    return SHADERS [current_render_context ()];
}
```

however, I can't find a cross-platform way to describe `current_render_context()`. Is there one? I don't necessarily need a cross-platform handle for the rendering context *object* itself, but any piece of identifying data which is unchanging and unique to each context will do.

What can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Use a platform-appropriate `*GetCurrentContext()` function:

```
// Windows
HGLRC wglGetCurrentContext(void)

// X11
GLXContext glXGetCurrentContext(void)

// OSX
CGLContextObj CGLGetCurrentContext(void)

// EGL
EGLContext eglGetCurrentContext(void)
```

It'll take a little bit of `#ifdef`ing but nothing too onerous.

If you use a framework like SDL2 [you can avoid even that](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GL_GetCurrentContext).